# Cesaro summable implies that $c_{n}/n$ goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Theorem.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}$ is Cesaro summable, then $c_{n}/n$ tends to $0$.

How to prove it?

Comment: Your title does not correspond to your question.

Comment: Please consider edit your post according to what you want to ask

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Cesàro summable means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_1+\cdots+c_n}n$ exists.
Note that $\frac{c_1+\cdots+c_n}n = \frac{c_1+\cdots+c_{n-1}}{n-1}\cdot(1-\frac1n)+\frac{c_n}n$.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!